# Java Deletion Function

Tags: java, linked-list

I have added the insertion function and display could anyone help 
me with the deletion That would be much appreciated.

```
public class Node 
{
   Object data;
   Node next;
}

public class LkList {
    public Node insertVar(Object var1, Node ls1) {
        Node p = new Node();
        p.data = var1;
        p.next = ls1;
        ls1 = p;
        return ls1;
    }

    public Node deleteVar(Object var1, Node ls1){
        // deletion function goes here
    }

    public void printL(Node ls1) {
        System.out.print("The lklist of variables is: ");

        Node p = ls1;

        while (p != null) {
            System.out.print("[" + p.data + "]" + "->");
            p = p.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385901/java-deletion-function and post again?

Comment: Deletion from **what?**

Comment: @Eran Because it was downvoted I guess.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @BrijRajKishore Actually it wasn't. It even had one answer (not mine).

Comment: i,m able now to insert variables and values but how can I delete what I inserted if I insert [a,1],[b.2],[c,3] how can I for example delete b,2

Comment: [saaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8969520/saaki) instead of pasting whole long code, please only specify the part in which you are in trouble. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I deleted bc it needed to edit and then peer review pop up and I think it takes days to approve my edit .. the previous answer did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java - how to delete a node from linkedlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902924/java-how-to-delete-a-node-from-linkedlist)

Answer (score 1):

Deletion of a Node will be as just removing its reference accessibility. 
In your case, you want to delete the node by comparing the given values of the Variable. So starting from the head node you have to compare each node's data (specific speaking it **Variable** Data). You have to compare the two Node's data and then simply break then simply apply the link list deletion logic. Only the main concern here is to compare the two nodes data. Don't compare the node by using

> .equals() method

```
    public Node deleteVar(Object var1, Node ls1) {
    if (ls1.data.varName.equals(var1.varName) && ls1.data.varValue.equals(var1.varValue)) { // If it is the first node which is to be deleted
        return ls1.next;
    }
    else {
        Node prev = ls1;

        while (prev.next != null) {
            if (prev.next.data.varName.equals(var1.varName) && prev.next.data.varValue.equals(var1.varValue)) {
                // skip the node by linking the previous one to the next one directly
                prev.next = prev.next.next;
                break;
            }
        }

        return ls1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you copy/paste my answer instead of editing it, you should at least write code that would properly compile. I have used `Object` for the data/variable, hence there is no name and value. I used `equals` to simplify the code as it makes it easier to concentrate on the linkedList logic. On top of that, I don't even know what equals should mean (just name or name and value?). Variable should define that in its `equals` method instead of writing it hard-wired in the linkedList.

Comment: Sorry forgive me. I wasn't aware of the above facts. And I will make corrections in my code as soon as possible

Answer (score -1):

From your code and your explanation I assume that `ls1` is the first node of your list and you want to remove the first node in the list that has `var1` as its `data`:

```
public Node deleteVar(Object var1, Node ls1)
{
    if (ls1.data.equals(var1))
    {
        //simply pop the first node
        return ls1.next;
    }
    else
    {
        Node prev = ls1;

        while (prev.next != null)
        {
            if (prev.next.data.equals(var1))
            {
                // skip the node by linking the previous one to the next one directly
                prev.next = prev.next.next;
                break;
            }
        }

        return ls1;
    }
}
```

Comment: well thank you very much ... really appreciate it..

Comment: You are welcome. For the next question you ask, try to be more concise. Don't know if you have seen that I have edited your question to remove unnecessary parts of your code (well, unnecessary for this question at least). It makes understanding what you ask much easier if you reduce your code snippets to the minimum. Also you might want to check the question I linked to in the comment under your question. The answers there are more detailed, and deal with `null` for example.

Comment: but in my code you got menu so when you choose 1 you can insert values with their variable .. lets say you run the code it asks 1- insert 2-display 3-delete 4-exit... and lets say you choose 1 insertion so it asks first to insert the variate(a) and then the value(2) etc.. however, when you want to delete it asks first to input the variable and then the value... im not good at explaining hope it helps

Comment: this is my first time on this web

Comment: Sure, maybe you could leave that part in, but I think after deleting that middle part (the class with the weird name) and the Menu, the code is pretty self explanatory. Just re-name `LkList` to `LinkedList`, and everybody will immediately understand what you need. It depends on each question how much code you need to show. Hope I could help. (Also, if you agree with the edits I made, you can accept (or improve) them to make them visible for the next reader.)

Comment: @MalteHartwig here you shouldn't use .equals() directly on the Variable. [See here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/pv9W3Hcdit) . It will produce the undesirable result.

Comment: @saaki Please see my code as I have warned, .equals() method cannot be used directly on the variable. [See here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/pv9W3Hcdit) for an example. And please accept the answer if it helped you to solve your query

Comment: Brij Raj Kishore

Comment: you are genius man you have solved i really was giving up may god bless you thank you so much

Comment: the only weird thing when I insert more than two elements and i want to delete, the first element i put in the linklist, code does not work other than than it is working GREAT

Comment: @saaki, make sure to do it like this: `Node ls1= lkList.deleteVar(var, ls1);`. You have to re-assign ls1, otherwise it won't work when removing the first node. Because in that case, `ls1` is never changed; we just return the second node without touching the first one.

Comment: thank you I,m gonna discuss this with my instructor I think he would love it